# Word/Phrase which could replace "serious" in "he was serious" in the context of telling the truth

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

**Edit:**

I want replace the word "serious" with a phrase or word of a similar meaning in the following context:

> Upon hearing what he had to say, I thought he was playing games with me, but he was serious.

I am looking for a word that has the same gravity as "serious" but more negative connotations, similar to "grave". But I find that "grave" doesn't fit particularly well within the above example.

Comment: When asking for a replacement word, it helps for you to say what qualities of you would like to find in the replacement, and why the existing word doesn't suit your requirements.

Comment: Sorry! I'm new on here. I edited to include more information.

Comment: No problem. Your edit makes it much clearer what you're after. By the way - welcome to EL&U!

Comment: I think your term "serious" works well for your example.

Comment: I agree, it fits the flow quite well. I was looking for a more negative word which might better suit the context.

Comment: Yes, I meant that "serious" conveys the sense of gravity you're describing. If you want to intensify the 'graveness' further, you could say he was "*utterly* serious".

Comment: But ***serious*** doesn't mean "truthful", except in the highly specific context of being contrasted with lighthearted "untrue" banter, etc. So are you looking for an antonym of ***playful***, or ***lying**?*

Comment: Another option might be **earnest**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sober](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sober), [somber](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/somber), [solemn](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solemn), and [grim](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grim) are all words that could work in this context.

e.g.

> Upon hearing what he had to say, I thought he was playing games with me, but his voice was grim.

Comment: I was going for a more negative connotation, similar to "grave". Sorry! I'll edit and put in that information.